# Mixing Tweets with Posts

Tags: posts, cache, twitter

I have a client who wants their blog to display both Posts and Tweets in chronological order. These should be mixed into the same feed. I didn't find any plugins that accomplished this, although there may be one I missed which someone could recommend.

I was thinking to pull the tweets and store them as a custom post type, and then just pull both post types when displaying, but Twitter's TOS does not allow the storing of the data.

Only option I see is to pull the tweets on page load, and then write a custom function to merge the two chronologically, which seems like a bit of work. Also, as far a caching the tweets, how can I go about this, considering that Twitter does not allow for storage of this information?

Does anyone have a recommendation on the best way to accomplish this? Also the most efficient?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I think the idea that Twitter's TOS precludes you saving tweets to your site is not something you should worry about. Tons of plugins do exactly this and ethically you have a right to back up your tweets. The answer implies this but I felt it's worth making explicit. If you wanted to merge two custom post types you can just give an array of post types to WP_Query in the 'post_type' argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this with [Twitter Tools](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-tools/). Basically it hooks up the blog to a Twitter feed, and for each new tweet creates a blog post. You can put twitter posts in a separate category (or add tags), and use that to style twitter-posts differently from regular posts, hide the comments field, whatever.

Hope this helps - good luck!

Comment: So you are saying that the blog automatically checks Twitter for new posts, and then creates a Wordpress post for this?

Comment: Yep. You do have to go through a few hoops to get Twitter authenticated - and it looks like the documentation isn't quite up to date, so check the WP forums for tips - but once you're connected it works pretty seamlessly. I've had a client using it for months and haven't heard of anything going wrong.

Comment: Cool. I will check it out. Sounds a lot easier than a custom implementation. Thanks!